# Angular Directives Template variables based on attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive that generates a Box div.

## /template/boxes.html

```
<box index=0></box>
<box index=1></box>
```

## /box.js

```
app.controller('BoxController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

 $scope.boxIndex = false;

}]);

app.directive('box', function () {

    return {
     restrict: 'E',
     templateUrl: '/partials/_box.html',
     link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.boxIndex = attrs.index;
     }
    }

});
```

## /partials/_box.html

```
<div class="box{{boxIndex}}"></div>
```

I'm getting the output as

```
<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="box1"></div>
```

instead of

```
<div class="box0"></div>
<div class="box1"></div>
```

Is there something else that I should be doing to make both the instances separate?

Comment: @Marc - shouldn't the partials template be <box ..> </box> as I'm using an element directive?

Comment: No, if you use the directive in the directive's template, you will run into recursive looping issues

Comment: Ah my mistake. I'll correct the question for future referencing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your directives are both sharing the parent controller's scope and are therefore accessing the same value. Since you're using interpolation, they both update to the last set value.

Use `scope: true` or `scope: {}` instead:

```
app.directive('box', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {}, // or scope: true
        templateUrl: '/partials/_box.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.boxIndex = attrs.index;
        }
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/7ib4AzAhMKYLqotr3379?p=preview)

Comment: Yes, I just added a scope property and I'm getting the proper divs. But what if I need to access some controller methods? How would I get access to those if I have a local scope? 



...
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.boxIndex = attrs.index;
    scope.methodOne(); // the method in the controller
}
...

Comment: -- UPDATE 

scope: true, // fixed that up